# is it possible to use the LUIS locally(without internet)

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

is it possible to use the LUIS locally(without internet). I have LUIS application in azure. However my organization firewall doesnt allow me to connect to LUIS from data center. Only allowed from laptop. If I host my .net chatbot and data base etc, in data center, conectivity to LUIS is not possible. I see files like greeting.lu, main.lu etc. is it possible to export and use the LUIS application locally with the chatbot?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run LUIS in a container on-prem (or wherever). However, the container needs to be able to make outgoing HTTP calls against the billing API. But no data apart from billing information (i.e. how many calls you made against you local LUIS) is being transmitted over the wire.

HOW-TO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto

Comment: "However my organization firewall doesnt allow me to connect to LUIS from data center" < he may not be able to send billing information, so the container option will not work after a few minutes

Comment: I am aware of that but that’s probably the best option there is so far if we wants to use LUIS. And the question would then be why his organization is concerned about it. If it is because of sending private data, the container option might indeed be a solution.

Comment: Sure. It was just a side not to your reply, as the OP states that the firewall is blocking.

Comment: @Gokul_NorthStar can you please comment if you need more help or accept the answer if this solves it for you?